# randomseed in LUA

Tags: random, lua

I am working on a code that randomizes numbers. I put `math.randomseed(os.time())` inside a loop. The code goes like this:

```
for i = 1, 1000 do
  math.randomseed( os.time() )
  j = math.random(i, row-one)
  u[i], u[j] = u[j], u[i]
  for k = 1, 11 do
     file:write(input2[u[i]][k], " ")
  end
  file:write"\n"
end
```

And when I run it several times, the whole output is always the same. Isn't the randomseed supposed to prevent repeats when re-run?

Comment: `os.time()` returns the same value during a second.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff so how do i make the whole results different when I re-run the code?

Comment: Don't run the same code twice within one second :-)

Comment: just use something like `os.time() - os.clock() * 1000` instead

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generating uniform random numbers in Lua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20154991/generating-uniform-random-numbers-in-lua)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Call `math.randomseed` *once* at the start of the program. No point calling it in a loop.

Answer (score 4):

Usually the first random values aren't truly random (but it never is truly random anyway, it's a pseudo-random number generator).
First set a randomseed, then randomly generate it a few times.
Try this code, for example:

```
math.randomseed( os.time() )
math.random() math.random() math.random()
for i = 1, 1000 do
  j = math.random(i, row-one)
  u[i], u[j] = u[j], u[i]
  for k = 1, 11 do
     file:write(input2[u[i]][k], " ")
  end
  file:write"\n"
end
```

However, you could try this from http://lua-users.org/wiki/MathLibraryTutorial:

```
-- improving the built-in pseudorandom generator
do
   local oldrandom = math.random
   local randomtable
   math.random = function ()
      if randomtable == nil then
         randomtable = {}
         for i = 1, 97 do
            randomtable[i] = oldrandom()
         end
      end
      local x = oldrandom()
      local i = 1 + math.floor(97*x)
      x, randomtable[i] = randomtable[i], x
      return x
   end
end
```

Comment: "Usually the first random values aren't truly random"
This makes no sense. If you give it the same seed, it will always generate the same number sequence. The first number is no more or less random than the 6 millionth.